# splitting strings using re.split

Tags: python, regex, django, string

I have multiple strings (>1000) of the form:

```
\r\nSenor Sisig\nThe Chairman\nCupkates\nLittle Green Cyclo\nSanguchon\nSeoul on Wheels\nKasa Indian\n\nGo Streatery\nWhip Out!\nLiba Falafel\nGrilled Cheese Bandits\r\n
```

The strings may have a whitespace before the '\n'

How do I split these strings (in an efficient way) so as to avoid getting any empty or duplicate (the whitespace case) elements?

I was using:

```
re.split(r'\r|\n', str)
```

EDIT:
some more examples:

```
\r\nThe Creme Brulee Cart \r\nCurry Up Now\r\nKoJa Kitchen\r\nAn the Go\r\nPacific Puffs\r\nEbbett's Good to Go\r\nFiveten Burger\r\nGo Streatery\r\nHiyaaa\r\nSAJJ\r\nKinder's Truck\r\nBlue Saigon\r
\r\nThe Chairman\r\nSanguchon\r\nSeoul on Wheels\r\nGo Streatery\r\nStreet Dog Truck\r\nKinder's Truck\r\nYummi BBQ\r\nLexie's Frozen Custard\r\nDrewski's Hot Rod Kitchen\r
\n An the Go \n Cheese Gone Wild \n Cupkates \n Curry Up Now \n Fins on the Hoof\n KoJa Kitchen\n Lobsta Truck \n Oui Chef \n Sanguchon\n Senor Sisig \n The Chairman \n The Rib Whip
```

thanks!

Comment: None of your example strings show any whitespace before the `\n` except for `\r\n`. Are you looking to just handle an optional `\r\n` as if it were `\n`, or is there something different you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Your example doesn't show any "whitespace before the `\n`" except for a single optional `\r`.

If that's all you're trying to handle, instead of splitting on either `\r` or `\n`, split on a possible `\r` and a definite `\n`:

```
re.split(r"\r?\n", s)
```

Of course that's assuming you don't have any bare `\r` without `\n` to handle. If you need to handle `\r`, `\r\n`, and `\n` all equally (similar to Python's universal newline support…):

```
re.split(r"\r|\n|(\r\n)", s)
```

Or, more simply:

```
re.split(r"(\r|\n)+", s)
```

If you want to remove leading spaces, tabs, multiple `\r`, etc., you could do that in the regexp, or just call `lstrip` on each result:

```
map(str.lstrip, re.split(r"\r|\n", s))
```

… but that can leave you with empty elements. You could filter those out, but it's probably better to just split on any run of whitespace that ends with a `\n` instead:

```
re.split(r"\s*\n", s)
```

That will still leave empty elements at the start and end, because your string starts and ends with newlines, and that's what `re.split` is supposed to do. If you want to eliminate them, you can either `strip` the string before parsing, or toss the end values after parsing:

```
re.split(r"\s*\n", s.strip())
re.split(r"\s*\n", s)[1:-1]
```

I think one of these last two is exactly what you want… but that's really just a guess based on the limited information you gave. If not, then one of the others (along with its explanation) should hopefully be enough for you to write what you really want.

---

From your new examples, it looks like what you really want to split on is any run of whitespace that includes at least one `\n`. And your input may or may not have newlines at the start and end (your first example has both, your second has `\r\n` at the start but nothing at the end…), and you want to ignore them if it does. So:

```
re.split(r"\s*\n\s*", s.strip())
```

---

However, at this point, it might be worth asking why you're trying to parse this as a string instead of as a text file. Assuming you got these from some file or file-like object, instead of this:

```
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    s = f.read()
    results = re.split(regexpr, s.strip())
```

… something like this might be a lot more readable, and more than fast enough (maybe not as fast as the optimal regexp, but still so fast that any wasted string-processing time is swamped by the actual file reading time anyway):

```
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    results = filter(None, map(str.strip, f))
```

Especially if you just want to iterate over this list once, in which case (assuming either Python 3.x, or using `ifilter` and `imap` from `itertools` if 2.x) this version doesn't have to read the whole file into memory and process it before you start doing your actual work.

Comment: @user2216194: OK, one more edit, then tell me if it does what you want…

Comment: I got this from the facebook graph api (from an events page which lists the vendors in the description) so I don't want extra storage. The problem is that the descriptions are not consistent so my solution (or the ones suggested) are working for some of the events but not all.

Comment: @user2216194: Does the graph API really return one giant string like this? If so… that sucks, but that's not your fault. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
re.split(r'[\s\n\r]+', str.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Just filter out the empty values

```
list(ifilter(None, re.split(r"\r|\n", your_string)))
```

Pythons regular expressions offer you the `\s` -character class which matches any whitespace  in `[ \t\n\r\f\v]` (unless UNICODE flag is set, then it depends on the character database in use).

As mentioned in the other answers (@abarnert), your regex *could* be `\s*\n` which is 0 or more whitespace ending with an `\n`. Below is an example.

```
In [1]: import re 

In [2]: from itertools import ifilter

In [3]: my_string = """\r\nSenor Sisig \nThe Chairman\nCupkates\nLittle Green Cyclo\nSanguchon\nSeoul on Wheels\nKasa Indian\n\nGo Streatery\nWhip Out!\nLiba Falafel\nGrilled Cheese Bandits\r\n"""

In [4]: list(ifilter(None, re.split(r"\s*\n", my_string)))
Out[4]: 
['Senor Sisig',
 'The Chairman',
 'Cupkates',
 'Little Green Cyclo',
 'Sanguchon',
 'Seoul on Wheels',
 'Kasa Indian',
 'Go Streatery',
 'Whip Out!',
 'Liba Falafel',
 'Grilled Cheese Bandits']
```

Note that I'm using `ifilter` from the [itertools package](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html). You could use `filter` or a list comp.

Like so:

```
[x for x in re.split("\s*\n", my_string) if x]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = "\r\nSenor Sisig\nThe Chairman\nCupkates\nLittle Green Cyclo\nSanguchon\nSeoul on Wheels\nKasa Indian\n\nGo Streatery\nWhip Out!\nLiba Falafel\nGrilled Cheese Bandits\r\n"
>>> [x for x in s.strip("\r\n").split("\n") if x]
['Senor Sisig', 'The Chairman', 'Cupkates', 'Little Green Cyclo', 'Sanguchon', 'Seoul on Wheels', 'Kasa Indian', 'Go Streatery', 'Whip Out!', 'Liba Falafel', 'Grilled Cheese Bandits']
```

If you insist on regex

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r"[\r\n]+", s.strip("\r\n"))
['Senor Sisig', 'The Chairman', 'Cupkates', 'Little Green Cyclo', 'Sanguchon', 'Seoul on Wheels', 'Kasa Indian', 'Go Streatery', 'Whip Out!', 'Liba Falafel', 'Grilled Cheese Bandits']
```

Comment: This works for his example, but only because his example doesn't actually demonstrate the problem. You're not stripping the extra "whitespace before the `\n`" that he asked about.

Comment: Huh? You mean like `[x.strip() for x in s.strip("\r\n").split("\n") if x]`

Comment: Maybe… but until he clarifies what he's actually asking (or, better, gives an example that actually demonstrates it), "maybe" is really the best anyone can say…