# Split newlines into paragraphs and remove empty lines

Tags: python, string

Im trying to split a text into paragraphs. I want to find the first line, and assign it to a variable, and the rest of the lines should be formated inside `<p></p>`

```
text = "Firstline

Secondline

Third line"
```

Here is what I have:

```
text = unicode(ws.description)
                
object.firstline = text.split('\n', 1)[0] #This works, and should not be wrapped in <p></p>


bodytext = text.partition('\n')[2]
                    
object.body = ''.join('<p>'+L+'</p>' for L in bodytext.split('\n'))
```

But `object.body` returns this value

```
object.body = "<p></p>
<p>Secondline</p>
<p></p>     
<p>Third line</p>
<p></p>"
```

How can I remove the empty lines, so I don't have any empty `<p></p>` ?

## Edit

Here is the working code (from answer of Ashwini Chaudhary)

```
text = unicode(ws.description)

if not "\n" in text:
    object.firstline = text
else:
    first, rest = text.split('\n', 1)
    
    object.firstline = first
    
    object.body = '\n'.join(u'<p>{}</p>'.format(x) for x in rest.splitlines() if x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly split at `'\n'` only once to get the first line and the rest of the lines:

```
>>> first, rest = text.split('\n', 1)
>>> first
'Firstline'
>>> rest
'\nSecondline\n\nThird line'
```

Now loop over rest of the lines(`rest.splitlines()`) and drop the empty lines using a simple `if` condition:

```
>>> print '\n'.join('<p>{}</p>'.format(x) for x in rest.splitlines() if x)
<p>Secondline</p>
<p>Third line</p>
```

Comment: I get this error `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`

Comment: @Garreth00 That means your text contains no newlines, i.e something like: `text = 'first line'`.

Comment: @Garreth00 `if '\n' not in text: print 'text contains only a single line'`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to determine if the string is empty *prior* to joining it.

Given:

```
>>> text = """Firstline
...
... Secondline
...
... Third line"""
```

This becomes:

```
>>> ''.join('<p>' + L + '</p>' for L in text.split('\n') if L)
'<p>Firstline</p><p>Secondline</p><p>Third line</p>'
```

`text.split` creates a list, which you're iterating through; `if L` checks for a non-empty value in that list.

Comment: @garreth-00 You should also keep in mind, that newlines can be `\r`, `\n` or `\r\n`. So, pay attention to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21840976/764182

Answer (score 0):

```
''.join('<p>'+L+'</p>' for L in bodytext.split('\n') if L)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.splitlines` for line boundaries and then `str.join` to join the strings.

```
text = """Firstline
Secondline
Third line"""

print '\n'.join('<p>'+l+'</p>' for l in text.splitlines() if l)
```

output:-

```
>>> 
<p>Firstline</p>
<p>Secondline</p>
<p>Third line</p>
```

To print last two lines,

```
text = text.splitlines[1:]
print '\n'.join('<p>'+l+'</p>' for l in text if l)
```

output:-

```
>>> 
<p>Secondline</p>
<p>Third line</p>
```